# Good way to handle missing AssociatedControlID

Tags: asp.net, html, controls

I have a medium sized project with a lot of pages. One of the things that I've noticed is that we have a lot of labels that have AssociatedControlID pointing to controls that are not visible. The target controls are set visible when a user has edit permissions, but not normally.

This means that the html generated in not valid, which we'd like to get as close to as possible.

I attempted to implement a new label, which overrides the existing label control and render the `for` attribute only when needed. This proved painful as much of the functionality required was set to internal in the `Label` class.

Is there a better way?

Comment: If the controls are not rendered, then why are the associated labels rendered at all ? Shouldn't the visibility/rendering apply to both the input control and the associated label ?

Comment: +1 just for the use of the "AssociatedControlID" property (or `<label for="MyInputField">` syntax), which I consider a very good practice and always try to encourage my team to use.

Answer (score 2):

Subclassing Label control is not that hard:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
   public class BetterLabel : Label
   {
      protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
      {
         Control control = FindControl(this.AssociatedControlID);
         if (control != null && !control.Visible)
            this.AssociatedControlID = "";

         base.OnPreRender(e);
      }
   }
}
```

Here's how to use BetterLabel:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc1" Namespace="MyNamespace"  %>
...
<uc1:BetterLabel ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label" AssociatedControlID="TextBox1" />
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
```